# Add hyperlink column to InfoPath 2010 repeating table

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I'm using InfoPath 2010 to customize a SharePoint 2010 list form. The Infopath form shows data from two SharePoint lists, a Parent list and Child list. The Parent list is the primary data connection. The Child list is a repeating table bound to a secondary data connection. 
I would like to add an "Open" link to each row in the repeating table that links to the full child record.

The link would be something like http://myserver/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId={LIST_GUID}&ID=THE_LIST_ITEM_ID.

To do this I bascially want to add a column to the repeating table and use XPath to generate the link tag but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, you simply add a new field to the repeating table with data-type "Hyperlink (anyURI) and then you set the default value of that field to "concact(http://myserver/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId=; LIST_GUID)" where as the LIST_GUID is a field of that same repeating table

i've created a test-form where ive done exactly that - http://db.tt/dPW7Gll